# Positioning UI controls without relying on centers

Tags: objective-c, ios6, interface-builder, constraints, autolayout

I'm creating a sample login screen to practice Auto Layout. In portrait mode, it looks like this.

[image]

However when I rotate to landspace mode, it looks like this.

[image]

Below are the constraints I have set in this layout.

[image]

I understand why this is happening. It is because I have a constraint for the User ID UILabel [ Vertical Space(196) ]. How can I position the UIlabel+UITextField set slightly below the horizontal center line of the screen when turned to Landscape?

I assume I can set maybe the middle label to Horizontal Center in Container and then have the other 2 labels positioned relative to that one. But what I'm looking for is a way to position them without the help of center positioning in container. I want them to position slightly below the horizontal center line. How can I do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any way to do that in IB, without using the center property -- you could make your views appear below the center by putting another label above User ID, but with no text in it, so it will be invisible. Center that one, and have all the others positioned relative to it.

Answer (score 0):

select all controls and select `Top space to superview`

[image]

Now select only textfields and select `Widths Equally`

[image]

This should work. If not, then let me know i will send you sample code or screens of constraints.